# Dynamic m-VRP ( fixed number of vehicles)

Tags: graph-theory, operations-research

I am working on a dynamic m-vrp problem, for this I have started to construct a heuristic (to solve the static vrp first), for m vehicles that are moving depots, I have chosen m remote customers that do not exceed a certain distance (customer-deposit) And I assigned them to my vehicles. After searching for the first customer for each vehicle, I apply the approche of the nearest neighbor. If you have any comments or ideas that could help me make this heuristic better, I would appreciate it.